How to find intersection of two ActiveRecord query results in Rails?
I am working on a Ruby on Rails project where I need to find records in a database that satisfy two different conditions on the same column.
The issue arose when I wanted to find patients who satisfy both of the following conditions. When I put the query into Ransack like this:
queries = {"groupings" => {
    "0" => {
      "c" => {
        "0" => {
          "a" => { "0" => { "name" => "disease_code" } },
          "p" => "eq",
          "v" => { "0" => { "value" => "1234" } }
        },
        "1" => {
          "a" => { "0" => { "name" => "disease_type" } },
          "p" => "in",
          "v" => { "0" => { "value" => "1" } }
        },
        "2" => {
          "a" => { "0" => { "name" => "disease_code" } },
          "p" => "eq",
          "v" => { "0" => { "value" => "4567" } }
        },
        "3" => {
          "a" => { "0" => { "name" => "flag" } },
          "p" => "in",
          "v" => { "0" => { "value" => "1" } }
        },
       }
      }
     }

patient.ransack(queries).result.to_sql

This is what gets returned:
select *
from patients p 
join patient_diseases pd
on p.id = pd.patient_id
where pd.disease_code in 1234 
and pd.disease_type = 1
and pd.disease_code in (4567)
and pd.flag in (1)

but I want SQL like this
select *
from patients p
join patient_diseases pd1
on p.id = pd1.patient_id
where pd1.disease_code = 1234 
and pd1.disease_type = 1
and exists (
    select 1
    from patient_diseases pd2
    where pd2.patient_id = p.id
    and pd2.disease_code = 4567
    and pd2.flag = 1
);

Instead, I am considering fetching the results for each condition separately and then finding the intersection of these results in the backend.
For example, I have a Patient model and I want to find patients that satisfy condition_1 and condition_2.
# Patients satisfying condition_1
patients_condition_1 = Patient.where(condition_1)

# Patients satisfying condition_2
patients_condition_2 = Patient.where(condition_2)

# Intersection of both conditions
intersecting_patients = patients_condition_1 & patients_condition_2

Is this a good approach, or is there a better way to achieve this in Rails? Any suggestions or improvements are highly appreciated!
PS: I know I could subquery but, there is so many different condition to find it.
So, I give up using a subquery.

It's a bad idea to use & — it will generate extra queries. patients_condition_1.or(patients_condition_2) or Patient.where('condition_1 OR condition_2') is better

@mechnicov
SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."patient_disease" IN ('1234') OR "patients"."patient_disease" IN ('5678')
For example:
Patient 1: 1234, 5678 Patient 2: 1234
If I use or, both Patient 1 and Patient 2 will be returned, which is not what I want.
or am i wrong?

My comment related to &. You shouldn't use it as indicated in the question for any queries

You use in predicate wrong way
You should use it such way
Patient.ransack(patient_disease_disease_code_in: %w[1234 4567))


This doesn't quite work if you need the specific combination of disease_code and disease_type.

There is a much easier way to get the same result:
Patient.joins(:patient_diseases)
       .where(
         patient_diseases: {
           disease_type: 1,
           disease_code: [1234, 4567]
         }
       )
       .group(:id)
       .having(PatientDiseases.arel_table[:id].count.eq(2))

This works if we can assume both have the same disease_type.
If you need an actual subquery you can write it with the query interface mixed with a tiny bit of Arel.
sub = PatientDiseases.where(
        disease_type: 1,
        disease_code: 1234
      )
      .where(
          # patient_diseases.patient_id = patients.id
          PatientDiseases.arel_table[:patient_id]
                         .eq(Patient.arel_table[:id])
      )

Patient
  .joins(:patient_diagnosis)
  .where(
    patient_diagnosis: {
      disease_type: 1,
      disease_code: 1234
    }
  )
  .where(sub.arel.exists)


I honestly don't know how to write this query with Ransack or if it's even possible.

reference by here https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/1011
so, instead of using ransack, I should use active record.
Patient.joins(LEFT JOIN patient_diseases pd1 on pd1.patient_id = patients.id).joins(LEFT JOIN patient_diseases pd2 on pd2.patient_id = patients.id).where(rd1.disease_code in (1234) and rd2.disease_code in (4567))


why not patients_condition_1.or(patients_condition_2) from @mechnikov?
